# Get game being streamed from user's activity on Discord

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm writing a discord bot in .net, and I need to get the name of the game being streamed by a user.

In discord.py, this is possible with https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Streaming.details.

I'd like to do this in discord.net, but 'Activity', along with Activity cast to Game and StreamingGame, all return the name of the stream (when streaming), not the actual name of the game. (RichGame gives a null reference exception.)

The game being played is visible when viewing a streaming user on Discord, but as far as I could see, not in the API. So how does discord.py get it?

I checked other libraries and it seems discord.py is the only one supporting it.

I tried to read the source code, but I'm not at all well-versed enough in python to understand it.

Example below:

```
var user = _client.GetGuild(0).GetUser(0);

Console.WriteLine($"Activity - {user.Activity.Name}");
Console.WriteLine($"Type - {user.Activity.Type}");
var Game = user.Activity as Game;
Console.WriteLine($"Game - {Game.Name}");
var StreamingGame = user.Activity as StreamingGame;
Console.WriteLine($"StreamingGame - {StreamingGame.Name}");
```

Returns:

```
Type - Streaming
Game - !giveaway ... Fallout 2 war eh das beste...
StreamingGame - !giveaway ... Fallout 2 war eh das beste...
```

Querying the the twitch API works, but seems excessive, considering it's available in the discord.py library.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: As far as d.net goes this is not possible yet. You could use the Twitch Lib and get it from there.

Comment: This issue is currently being tracked and fixed at https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/pull/1237